# "Please check the 'iss' claim" error when sending JWT to the /token API operation

Tags: box-api

I'm getting this response when calling the /token operation with a JWT on the Box OAuth 2 API:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Please check the 'iss' claim."
}
```

I've checked and double-check the value of the iss claim in the JWT which is defined as this at **https://box-content.readme.io/docs/app-auth**:

```
iss = The API key of the service that created the JWT assertion.
```

No matter what I've tried I get this error.

This occurred after setting the App's API key for Custom Applications in the "business Settings" -> Apps configuration for my account.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to srt32 I was able to use the utility at jwt.io to realise that I was calling JSON.stringyfy when I shouldn't have. it was adding double quotes around by string which caused them to be escaped with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `Api Key` is identical to the `client_id`. Find it at `https://app.box.com/developers/services/edit/<your_id_here>`. Are you using the correct key and id?

Comment: Thanks for the reply srt32..... but, yes, I've checked and they are the same thing, and I have sent the those values.

Comment: Sorry, good luck! If you haven't found it already, http://jwt.io/ can be really helpful for checking assertions.

Comment: Thanks srt32...I hadn't found jwt.io.
It revealed something interesting. My header looks like: `{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "\"o54ampdz\""
}` and my Payload is `{
  "iss": "\"28tafftz8ezxgrr7i0hrfg0imy7624n3\"",
  "sub": "542091",
  "box_sub_type": "enterprise",
  "aud": "https://api.box.com/oauth2/token",
  "jti": "1446129997123456",
  "exp": 1446130047,
  "iat": 1446129997
}` So it looks like I'm adding some spurious backslashes